# Qbs does not pick Clang in the tool chain configuration

Tags: clang, llvm, qbs

I have installed LLVM 5.0 on Windows 10 x64. When I call `clang++ --version` from `cmd` the message below is displayed.

```
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\LLVM\bin
```

But when I call `qbs setup-toolchains --detect` in the resulting list neither clang nor clang++ is in. If I call `qbs config --list profiles` both clang and clang++ are not in the list. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the --detect option only looks for MSVC and mingw installations. Use the explicit mode instead:

```
qbs setup-toolchains C:\LLVM\bin\clang.exe clang
```

Comment: Thanks, though Qbs was able to detect GCC (from MinGW64)!

Comment: You are right, I overlooked this in the code. Mingw compilers are always considered, regardless of the host platform.